# Can Sony employees see you through the Playstation 4 camera?

Tags: ps4

If you're using PS4 camera for PSVR or PlayRoom or Just Dance etc, when your camera is on and captured on TV, do employees from Sony see you through the camera, or can you only see your self and that's it?

Comment: Like... Sony employees? I suppose there's always the risk, since it's their hardware/software. But something tells me they have much better things to do than spy on everyone with a PS camera anyway, even if they wanted to.

Comment: Can you clarify which employees are these?

Comment: @MBorg Their might be tons of employees but I am not talking about a specific worker, I am asking are the Sony employees viewing you directly from the camera besides you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can do it, in the terms of use and conditions there is a clause in which it is specified that they could be recording, it also happens with xbox.

That is why it is so important to read the terms and conditions.

Even so, they do not go camera to camera watching what you do, because for this they must ask you for explicit permission. Also if they did spy on you this would be a very serious problem for the company.

You should worry more about the external hackers, that they could enter your console without you knowing and recording you.

This has a very simple solution, when you don't use the camera, just cover it with a cloth or something.